# Force all methods of a class to have specific signature using a decorator

Tags: typescript, types

I'm writing a decorator that receives a class instance as a parameter, and would require all methods of this class to return this. The issue I'm having is that in the class instance there are also other fields that do not conform to this signature (i.e. `new`, or `prototype`).

How could I fix this? This is what I have:

The usage of the decorator I'm aiming for:

```js
@Migrates(ProductCreated)
class EventMigration {
  public bar (a: Record<string, any>): ProductCreated {
    // ...
  }

  public foo (a: Record<string, any>): ProductCreated {
    // ...
  }
}
```

The decorator definition:

```js
interface Class<T> {
  new (...args: any[]): T
}

type Foo<T, V> = {
  [P in keyof T]
  : T[P] extends (old: Record<string, any>) => V
  ? 'it works!'
  : 'nope!'
}

function Migrates<T, V>(y: Class<V>) {
  return (x: Foo<T, V>): void => {}
}
```

---

In theory it should fail if the signature of one of the methods is not the same as defined in `Foo`, but if I do so, no compilation errors appear.

Comment: This sounds like you want to check whether a class is correctly set up to return the type in methods given in `Migrates`. Why double checking things here? Maybe I misunderstood, but isnt this easier achieved by an interface that enforces a type with its index access type declaration?

Comment: Yes, but apart from that, `Migrates` does another bunch of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a weird behavior of TypeScript's closures. If I specify the type parameters of `Migrates` in the return type it works.

Solved it this way:

```js
// Required to tell the compiler that it has atleast a constructor
export interface Class<TReflected> {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  new (...args: any[]): TReflected
}

// Constrains the properties to have the same type
type HomogenizePropertyTypes<Type, TPropertyType> = {
  [K in keyof Type]: TPropertyType
}

// The type that we want to use for our methods
type MigrationMethod<TConcept> = (x: Record<string,any>) => TConcept

// This type constrains the properties of the first parameter to be of
// the type MigrationMethod, the return type is specified by the second parameter
type Migration<TMigration, TConcept> = HomogenizePropertyTypes<TMigration, MigrationMethod<TConcept>>

// The decorator function, it is curried, accepts a class that constrains the
// return type of the methods, and then the class that it will constrain at
// the type level. After that, we can do whatever we want with it.
function Migrates<TConcept>(
  concept: Class<TConcept>
): <TMigration>(
  k: Class<Migration<TMigration, TConcept>>
) => void {
  return (klass) => {
    return {} as any   // Here we would do the rest of the stuff we want
  }
}
```